# Linking: with ld: cannot find -lc

Tags: linux, linker, ld, ubuntu

My system is: **Kubuntu**
Linux ubuntu 3.8.0-23-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 29 20:24:54 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

I am trying to run this command:

ld -o loader loader.o startup.o start.o -lc -T linking_script -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2

and I am getting the following error:

ld: cannot find -lc

I also tried this:
sudo yum install glibc-static
But got this error and couldn't find a way to add the repo's to it:
There are no enabled repos.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Why don't you link with the `gcc` command?

Answer (score 1):

Check LIBRARY_PATH env variable.

Try adding -L<Library Directory>.

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable is set up correctly.

I have -lc

Could you be more specific as to what I need to add.
Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, it's LIBRARY_PATH, not LD_LIBRARY_PATH. And you may try something like "ld -L/usr/lib/x86-linux-gnu/ -o loader loader.o startup.o start.o -lc -T linking_script -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2" (-L add a directory to the search paths for libraries)

Answer (score 1):

The man page for `ld` suggests that it has the following syntax:

```
ld [options] objfile ...
```

So, you need to put all options before the files. For example:

```
ld -o loader -lc -T linking_script -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 loader.o startup.o start.o
```